# Java Generics Compilation Error - Do not understand the error

Tags: java, generics

I know many ask such problems, but I really do not get this one.

(If you need more code, please tell)

```
public class QuestionManager<Question extends Component & IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>>

public class AccountingQuestionManager<Question extends Component & IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>> extends QuestionManager<Question>

public interface IQuestion<DataStorage extends IAnswerStorage>
```

`IAnswerStorage` is an empty interface

These are my 3 generic classes I need for explaining. In a `QuestionManager` the questions need to be questions (`IQuestions`) [with storage specified]

I now tried the following in the hope that it allows any questions, which are components as well.

```
QuestionManager<? extends Component & IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>> manager = new AccountingQuestionManager<>(
            "Test test", this);
```

I also have a function to add questions to a pool of questions:

```
manager.addQuestion(question);
```

But I get the 2 following errors:

```
Incorrect number of arguments for type QuestionManager<Question>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends Component, IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>>
```

```
Syntax error on token "&", , expected
```

Thanks so much for your help. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression

```
public class QuestionManager<Question extends Component & IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>>
```

you are declaring a type **parameter** named `Question` which is a subtype of `Component` and of `IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>`. That is, the type parameter `Question` has multiple bounds.

In this expression

```
QuestionManager<? extends Component & IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>> manager = new AccountingQuestionManager<>("Test test", this);
```

what you are attempting to do is declare a type **argument** for the `QuestionManager` type. A type argument cannot be declared to have multiple bounds. A type argument, by definition, already is a type with whatever bounds it has. You can't redefine it in the expression.

[Here are the syntax rules for type arguments.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the generic `&` in a *class* declaration, but not in *variable* assignment. You can safely do

```
QuestionManager<?> manager = //...
```

because it is guaranteed in the specification of the type parameter `Question` that it will already fit `? extends Component & IQuestion<? extends IAnswerStorage>`.

Comment: @Reisi007 How does it not work? What problems do you run into when using my solution?

Comment: If I use <?> then the type for addQuestion(Question) is ?. And I cannot add anything from type "?". Thanks for that try, but Java is not clever enough for this. Anyway, I found a working solution

Answer (score 0):

So that is the way I was able to solve my specific problem (which I would not be able to, if I would be less generic)
QuestionManager:

```
public class QuestionManager<Question extends IQuestion<? extends AnswerStorage>>
```

extends ExtBorderLayout

And the "addQuestion" method looks like the following

```
public <QuestionComponent extends IQuestion<? extends AnswerStorage> & Component> void addQuestion(
        QuestionComponent question)
```

So, making the method generic did the job for me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use '&' in the generic part when declaring a variable. It only works when declaring a generic class. When declaring a variable/field that uses a generic class, always provide concrete classes/interfaces for the generic parameters.
e.g., `QuestionManager<Question>`

Comment: You can use `&` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Oh my bad. I'll adapt the answer

Comment: Since when does `QuestionManager` have two type parameters?

Comment: I feel embarrassed... I guess I should get some sleep. Thanks for pointing this out.